# protect jwplayer video from hotlinking in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwplayer, hotlinking

I want to check if the request from is browser then expose the video cdn link to jwplayer. I want to make hard video from download.

My routes code is

```
 4   match "/assets/protect/:id.:format" => "streams#show"
```

My controller code is

```
  1 class StreamsController < ApplicationController
  2   def show
  3     self.response.headers["Location"] = Video.find(params[:id]).video.url.safe # here is the    condition if request is from browser
  4     render nothing: true, layout: false
  5   end
  6 end
```

My JS code

```
  2     jwplayer("video-player-container").setup({
  3       file: "/assets/protect/<%= @video.id %>.flv",
  4       wmode: 'transparent',
  5       flashplayer: "/jwplayer/player.swf",
  6       players: [{ type: "flash", src: "/jwplayer/player.swf" }, { type: "html5" }]
  7     });
```

is this possible or any other alternate solution?

regards

V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def show
  send_data Video.find(params[:id]).video.url.safe_url, type: "video/mp4", :disposition=>'inline'
end
```

Try this!